# my linear algebra question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that
$A = (a,b,c,d)$
is a $2 \times 2$ matrix such that $A B = B A$ for all $2 \times 2$ matrices $B$. Show that $a = d, b = 0, c = 0$. Deduce that the only such matrices are scalar multiples of the identity matrix.

Comment: My teacher gave me it. @Botond

Comment: Sorry, I missread it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Write that $A$ commutes with the matrix $E_{11}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0 \\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and with the matrix $J=\begin{pmatrix}0&1 \\1&0 \end{pmatrix}$.